# Проблема отрисовки btBoxShape в OpenGL 4.6

Tags: c++, opengl, графика

А расскажите пожалуйста как отрисовать объект btBoxShape, а точнее как получить его размер.
Вот пример отрисовки фигуры шар в моём коде:

```
// get btTransform data
btTransform transform;
body->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(transform);

// set varibles
glm::mat4 translate, rotate, scaling, matModel;
translate = rotate = scaling = matModel = glm::mat4(1.0f);

// scale
scaling = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), scale); // scale = размер заданный пользователем
float rad = ((btSphereShape*)body->getCollisionShape())->getRadius();
scaling = glm::scale(scaling, glm::vec3(rad));

// translate
btVector3 btPos = transform.getOrigin();
translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(btPos.x(), btPos.y(), btPos.z()));

// rotate
btQuaternion rotation = transform.getRotation();
rotation.normalize();
if (rotation.getAngle() > 0.0)
{
    glm::quat q = glm::normalize(engine::math::bulletToGlm(rotation));
    rotate = glm::mat4(1.0f) * glm::mat4_cast(q);
}

// get final 3d model matrix
matModel = translate * rotate * scaling;

// renderer
program.setMat4("model", matModel);
model->Draw(program, texture);
```

А как сделать scaling, только с btBoxShape? Гайд в котором я изучаю bullet приводятся примеры отрисовки на OpenGL 1.0. Поэтому я не знаю как это сделать. А других гайдов я не нашёл.